# replace value in varchar(max) field with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that contains text field with placeholders. Something like this:

```
Row Notes  
1.  This is some notes ##placeholder130## this ##myPlaceholder##, #oneMore#. End.
2.  Second row...just a ##test#.
```

*(This table contains about 1-5k rows on average. Average number of placeholders in one row is 5-15).*

Now, I have a lookup table that looks like this:

```
Name             Value
placeholder130    Dog
myPlaceholder     Cat
oneMore           Cow
test              Horse
```

*(Lookup table will contain anywhere from 10k to 100k records)*

I need to find the fastest way to join those placeholders from strings to a lookup table and replace with value. So, my result should look like this (1st row):

> This is some notes Dog this Cat, Cow. End.

What I came up with was to split each row into multiple for each placeholder and then join it to lookup table and then concat records back to original row with new values, but it takes around 10-30 seconds on average.

Comment: Can you post the current solution that takes 10-30 seconds?

Comment: Have you considered using SQL CLR?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, Yes, my server has CLR enabled, but I was not able to pass Tables to a CLR, AFAIK CLRs do not allow to pass datatables.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  And I echo Nathan Skerts comment: it really would help immensely to see the current code.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, SQL-server-2008-r2 standard edition. I will try to extract relevant part of the code from my stored proc and post it tomorrow.

Comment: With such a big lookup table, you really need to make it permanent, not temporary, and give it a clustered index on Name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I second the comment that tsql is just not suited for this operation, but if you must do it in the db here is an example using a function to manage the multiple replace statements.

Since you have a relatively small number of tokens in each note (5-15) and a very large number of tokens (10k-100k) my function first extracts tokens from the input as *potential* tokens and uses that set to join to your lookup (dbo.Token below). It was far too much work to look for an occurrence of *any* of your tokens in each note.

I did a bit of perf testing using 50k tokens and 5k notes and this function runs really well, completing in <2 seconds (on my laptop). Please report back how this strategy performs for you.

**note:** In your example data the token format was not consistent (`##_#, ##_##, #_#`), I am guessing this was simply a typo and assume all tokens take the form of ##TokenName##.

```
--setup
    if object_id('dbo.[Lookup]') is not null
        drop table dbo.[Lookup];
    go
    if object_id('dbo.fn_ReplaceLookups') is not null
        drop function dbo.fn_ReplaceLookups;
    go

    create table dbo.[Lookup] (LookupName varchar(100) primary key, LookupValue varchar(100));
    insert into dbo.[Lookup]
        select '##placeholder130##','Dog' union all
        select '##myPlaceholder##','Cat' union all
        select '##oneMore##','Cow' union all
        select '##test##','Horse';
    go

    create function [dbo].[fn_ReplaceLookups](@input varchar(max))
    returns varchar(max)
    as
    begin

        declare @xml xml;
        select @xml = cast(('<r><i>'+replace(@input,'##' ,'</i><i>')+'</i></r>') as xml);

        --extract the potential tokens
        declare @LookupsInString table (LookupName varchar(100) primary key);
        insert into @LookupsInString
            select  distinct '##'+v+'##'
            from    (   select  [v] = r.n.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
                                [r] = row_number() over (order by n)
                        from    @xml.nodes('r/i') r(n)
                    )d(v,r)
            where   r%2=0;

        --tokenize the input
        select  @input = replace(@input, l.LookupName, l.LookupValue)
        from    dbo.[Lookup] l
        join    @LookupsInString lis on 
                l.LookupName = lis.LookupName;

        return @input;
    end
    go          
    return            

--usage
    declare @Notes table ([Id] int primary key, notes varchar(100));
    insert into @Notes
        select 1, 'This is some notes ##placeholder130## this ##myPlaceholder##, ##oneMore##. End.' union all
        select 2, 'Second row...just a ##test##.';

    select  *,
            dbo.fn_ReplaceLookups(notes)
    from    @Notes;
```

Returns:

```
Tokenized
--------------------------------------------------------
This is some notes Dog this Cat, Cow. End.
Second row...just a Horse.
```

Comment: In my particular case your solution works best. Thanks a lot for you answer!

Answer (score 9):

You could try to split the string using a numbers table and rebuild it with `for xml path`.

```
select (
       select coalesce(L.Value, T.Value)
       from Numbers as N
         cross apply (select substring(Notes.notes, N.Number, charindex('##', Notes.notes + '##', N.Number) - N.Number)) as T(Value)
         left outer join Lookup as L
           on L.Name = T.Value
       where N.Number <= len(notes) and
             substring('##' + notes, Number, 2) = '##'
       order by N.Number
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from Notes
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66938/2)

I borrowed the string splitting from [this blog post by Aaron Bertrand](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: Nice script Mikael! This one runs just a bit slower than mine (10s vs 2s) but is much more consise. Well done sir.

Comment: @NathanSkerl Thank you. I have not done any performance testing on this but I guess a clustered key on `Lookup.Name` would be most helpful. I also think this is kind of what OP is already doing. *"split each row into multiple for each placeholder and then join it to lookup table and then concat records back to original row with new values"* I added this one because it was missing :) and I perhaps did a better job splitting a string. Also, using `value` to fetch the string from XML is much slower than not using `value` but you will get into trouble with `<>&` if you don't.

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server is not very fast with string manipulation, so this is probably best done client-side.  Have the client load the entire lookup table, and replace the notes as they arrived.

Having said that, it can of course be done in SQL.  Here's a solution with a recursive CTE.  It performs one lookup per recursion step:

```
; with  Repl as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by l.name) rn
        ,       Name
        ,       Value
        from    Lookup l
        )
,       Recurse as
        (
        select  Notes
        ,       0 as rn
        from    Notes
        union all
        select  replace(Notes, '##' + l.name + '##', l.value)
        ,       r.rn + 1
        from    Recurse r
        join    Repl l
        on      l.rn = r.rn + 1
        )
select  *
from    Recurse
where   rn = 
        (
        select  count(*)
        from    Lookup
        )
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a9d3/3/0)

Another option is a `while` loop to keep replacing lookups until no more are found:

```
declare @notes table (notes varchar(max))

insert  @notes
select  Notes
from    Notes

while 1=1
    begin

    update  n
    set     Notes = replace(n.Notes, '##' + l.name + '##', l.value)
    from    @notes n
    outer apply
            (
            select  top 1 Name
            ,       Value
            from    Lookup l
            where   n.Notes like '%##' + l.name + '##%'
            ) l
    where   l.name is not null

    if @@rowcount = 0
        break
    end   

select  *
from    @notes
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a9d3/1/0)

Comment: Thank you for the nice script. This one runs really slow for my set of data. Even slower than splitting and joining. What if I do not need to update the table? can I do this in a single select? or do you know if it makes sense to write a CLR that uses regex?

Comment: Added a second solution, how does that perform?  CLR's are not allowed where I work, but I'm positive you can do a simple replacement without a regex.

Comment: Second approach is mindblowing! It works awesome for small numbers of lookups and large numbers of Notes (I have up to 1k total notes), but as soon as I try all lookups (15k) it takes minutes to execute. I'm not sure if there's a way to optimize this though. One thing that I notice is that only handful (5-20) lookup fields are used in one query from all 15k available. Maybe I can prescan notes somehow and only use those lookups instead of all 15k iterations?

Comment: Why OUTER APPLY + WHERE IS NOT NULL? Wouldn't replacing it with just CROSS APPLY do the same?

Comment: [It appears](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a9d3/6) SQL Server is smart enough to recognise the two are the same thing. (The plan produced for the CROSS APPLY version is identical to your query's one.) So it's probably a matter of taste and/or clarity (both are subjective anyway).

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE (org, calc, [Notes], [level]) AS
(
    SELECT [Notes], [Notes], CONVERT(varchar(MAX),[Notes]), 0 FROM PlaceholderTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  CTE.org, CTE.[Notes],
        CONVERT(varchar(MAX), REPLACE(CTE.[Notes],'##' + T.[Name] + '##', T.[Value])), CTE.[level] + 1
    FROM    CTE
    INNER JOIN LookupTable T ON CTE.[Notes] LIKE '%##' + T.[Name] + '##%'

)

SELECT DISTINCT org, [Notes], level FROM CTE
WHERE [level] = (SELECT MAX(level) FROM CTE c WHERE CTE.org = c.org)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7898/3)

Check the below devioblog post for reference

[**devioblog post**](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/multiple-string-replaces-with-t-sql-ctes/)

Answer (score 1):

To get speed, you can preprocess the note templates into a more efficient form.  This will be a sequence of fragments, with each ending in a substitution.  The substitution might be NULL for the last fragment.

```
Notes
Id     FragSeq    Text                    SubsId
1      1          'This is some notes '   1
1      2          ' this '                2
1      3          ', '                    3
1      4          '. End.'                null
2      1          'Second row...just a '  4
2      2          '.'                     null

Subs
Id  Name               Value
1   'placeholder130'   'Dog'
2   'myPlaceholder'    'Cat'
3   'oneMore'          'Cow'
4   'test'             'Horse'
```

Now we can do the substitutions with a simple join.

```
SELECT Notes.Text + COALESCE(Subs.Value, '') 
FROM Notes LEFT JOIN Subs 
ON SubsId = Subs.Id WHERE Notes.Id = ?
ORDER BY FragSeq
```

This produces a list of fragments with substitutions complete.  I am not an MSQL user, but in most dialects of SQL you can concatenate these fragments in a variable quite easily:

```
DECLARE @Note VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @Note = COALESCE(@Note, '') + Notes.Text + COALSCE(Subs.Value, '') 
FROM Notes LEFT JOIN Subs 
ON SubsId = Subs.Id WHERE Notes.Id = ?
ORDER BY FragSeq
```

Pre-processing a note template into fragments will be straightforward using the string splitting techniques of other posts.

Unfortunately I'm not at a location where I can test this, but it ought to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know how it will perform with 10k+ of lookups.
how does the old dynamic SQL performs?

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand  NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sqlCommand  = N'PlaceholderTable.[Notes]'

SELECT @sqlCommand  = 'REPLACE( ' + @sqlCommand  + 
                      ', ''##' + LookupTable.[Name] + '##'', ''' + 
                      LookupTable.[Value] + ''')'  
FROM LookupTable

SELECT @sqlCommand  = 'SELECT *, ' + @sqlCommand  + ' FROM PlaceholderTable'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7898/4/0)

Comment: This one is super slow to construct a query. Anyways, it throws an error:
Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

Answer (score 0):

And now for some recursive CTE.

If your indexes are correctly set up, this one should be *very fast* or *very slow*. SQL Server always surprises me with performance extremes when it comes to the r-CTE...

```
;WITH T AS (
  SELECT
    Row,
    StartIdx = 1,                                  -- 1 as first starting index
    EndIdx = CAST(patindex('%##%', Notes) as int), -- first ending index
    Result = substring(Notes, 1, patindex('%##%', Notes) - 1)
                                                   -- (first) temp result bounded by indexes
  FROM PlaceholderTable -- **this is your source table**
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    pt.Row,
    StartIdx = newstartidx,                        -- starting index (calculated in calc1)
    EndIdx = EndIdx + CAST(newendidx as int) + 1,  -- ending index (calculated in calc4 + total offset)
    Result = Result + CAST(ISNULL(newtokensub, newtoken) as nvarchar(max))
                                                   -- temp result taken from subquery or original
  FROM 
    T
    JOIN PlaceholderTable pt -- **this is your source table**
      ON pt.Row = T.Row
    CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT newstartidx = EndIdx + 2              -- new starting index moved by 2 from last end ('##')
    ) calc1
    CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT newtxt = substring(pt.Notes, newstartidx, len(pt.Notes))
                                                   -- current piece of txt we work on
    ) calc2
    CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT patidx = patindex('%##%', newtxt)     -- current index of '##'
    ) calc3
    CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT newendidx = CASE 
        WHEN patidx = 0 THEN len(newtxt) + 1
        ELSE patidx END                            -- if last piece of txt, end with its length
    ) calc4
    CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT newtoken = substring(pt.Notes, newstartidx, newendidx - 1)
                                                   -- get the new token
    ) calc5
    OUTER APPLY(
      SELECT newtokensub = Value
      FROM LookupTable
      WHERE Name = newtoken                        -- substitute the token if you can find it in **your lookup table**
    ) calc6
  WHERE newstartidx + len(newtxt) - 1  <= len(pt.Notes)  
                                                   -- do this while {new starting index} + {length of txt we work on} exceeds total length
) 
,lastProcessed AS (
  SELECT 
    Row, 
    Result,
    rn = row_number() over(partition by Row order by StartIdx desc)
  FROM T 
)                                                  -- enumerate all (including intermediate) results
SELECT *
FROM lastProcessed
WHERE rn = 1                                       -- filter out intermediate results (display only last ones)
```